"Anchor deploy" deploys immutable program
I am using Anchor 0.30.1 which is the latest version.
I used to use Anchor 0.30.0 and anchor  deploy has deployed upgradeable programs.
But after upgrading to 0.30.1, it deploys immutable program.
This is the solscan link.
https://solscan.io/account/2NCDH9yihzmeApVkVy9a89uRptMHCf6jHZS6YfNd9WFC?cluster=devnet
Anyone could help with this problem?

This looks like it might be a solscan bug, the Solana explorer properly shows this program as upgradeable: https://explorer.solana.com/address/2NCDH9yihzmeApVkVy9a89uRptMHCf6jHZS6YfNd9WFC?cluster=devnet

Oh, Right. Thank you.
